# How to count number of value occurrences in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, count, hiveql

I have a table that I am trying to gather metrics on the number of times a value appears in the tables based by the value itself. Below is my table:

**Table 1**

```
id | type 
1,   law
1,   law
1,   law
2,   business
2,   business
2,   business
3,   science
4,   medicine
```

**Here is the SQl query I am using:**

```
select type, count(distinct type) my_count from table1 group by type;
```

**My output is:**

```
type    | my_count
science,   1
medicine,  1
```

**It excludes the other records. I want my output to essentially be:**

```
type    | my_count
science,    1
medicine,   1
business,   3
law,        3
```

I know this may seem like an easy task but I am new to HiveSQl. Any ideas or suggestions would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want just `count(*)`:

```
select type, count(*) as my_count
from table1
group by type;
```

This is kind of ironic.  Usually people are trying `count()` and they need to learn about `count(distinct)`.

Do note that your version should not be filtering out any `type` values.  However, the counts would always be `1`.